# Problem in adding values to the database when apps will terminate

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have to save my application data so i am adding all the database while application quit and when apps open, i am retrieving all the records.

It works perfect only for two times means first apps installed, it will save data for app termination 1 and apps termination 2. But then after it doesn't save my data to the database or third time termination. I checked that all values are coming and everything goes fine, but it is not saving for third time termination . There is not error message also.

Does anyone face this problem? Can any one guide me?.

Thanks,
iPhone Dev.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving to a log file to see that the db saving completes. Something like

```
Write to file ("save started")
... call the save
Write to file ("save ended")
```

This way you can discover if this code is (A) called at all, or (B) fails half way through.

Comment: Yes, I am checking log also. It adds data for two times of termination. It stop at half way for third time without any error message.